# Do I need to pay income taxes for the money I earn online from a foreign website?

Tags: income-tax, india, self-employment

I work for a website based in Europe and they pay me every month to my bank account (salary account). Every time I receive funds, I will get a call from the bank for confirmation and they ask for the source and reason. I will tell them the website name and software consultancy. They deduct some amount as charges, and credit the remaining to my account.

The question is: do I need to pay income taxes for this money I earned online?

Comment: What are your countries of citizenship and residence? US? If so, is the bank account US or foreign?

Comment: "a website based in Europe" 
Where does the website's company operate, and where is it registered?  And as mentioned, where are you living, and what nationalities do you hold?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you do.

Depending on your country's laws and regulations, since you're not an employee but a self employed, you're likely to be required to file some kind of a tax return with your country's tax authority, and pay the income taxes on the money you earn.

You'll have to tell us more about the situation, at least let us know what country you're in, for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, yes, you would have to pay. If you are in the US, or a citizen of the US, then IRC Sec. 61 would levy tax on all income. Even if you find money on the ground, that will generally be taxable income (the treasure trove doctrine). If you are paying foreign income taxes, the US may allow credit.